# Phonegap file structure

Tags: cordova

I created a Phonegap project, and it has the following folder structure:

```
merges
platforms
plugins
www
```

I've seen Phonegap projects on the web with a radically different folder structure:

```
assets
bin
gen
libs
res
src
```

Is that folder structure for Phonegap 2?

Answer (score 1):

Cordova is the one with the Resources, Libs, Assets, Phonegap has the structure of your first mergers, platforms etc. I had the same question and realized this after comparing files on an older app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "parent" folder wich is

> ProjectName/www

This folder contains your code HTML, JS, CSS of your application and correspond to your first structure.

When you run the following command

```
phonegap platform add android
phonegap build android
```

It will create an android project application using the android structure which is your second structure contained into

> ProjectName/platforms/android

the www folder will be copied into your assets folder.